# Github3.py returns only issues till May 2020 (1000 issues) but I need for past 2 years and then wish to plot using Line Chart

Tags: json, python-3.x, github-api, pygithub, github3.py

```
import github3, json, os.path



gh = github3.login(token="d6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")#Access token 

                 
REPO = 'angular'#name of repository
FILENAME_ISSUES = REPO + 'issues2.json'#name of JSON which saves issues

f = open(FILENAME_ISSUES, 'w')
for issue in gh.search_issues('repo:angular/angular created:>2018-07-01'):         
            label_name=[]
            data={}
            current_issue = issue.as_json()
            current_issue = json.loads(current_issue)
            data['issue_number']=current_issue["number"]                                     
            data['created_at']= current_issue["created_at"][0:10]                 
            if current_issue["closed_at"] == None:
                data['closed_at']= current_issue["closed_at"]
            else:
                data['closed_at']= current_issue["closed_at"][0:10]               
            for label in current_issue["labels"]:
                label_name.append(label["name"])                               
            data['labels']= label_name
            data['State'] = current_issue["state"]                                
            data['Author'] = current_issue["user"]["login"]                      
            out=json.dumps(data)                                                  
            f.write(out+ '\n')
f.close()
```

This is a snippet of the code I am using. It is returning only 1000 issues up to May 2020 but I need for the past 2 years. Could someone please help and tell me where am I going wrong or suggest an alternative? Also, if possible how do I plot issues for multiple repositories on Line Chart?